# Glossy Button in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, button

How to make glossy button in Vb.Net?

or

how change button background on mouseover?

Comment: What are you using? WinForms, webforms, silverlight, WPF?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **WinForms**, you usually achieve this by creating a new class inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase`.

From there, overwrite `OnMouseEnter`, `OnMouseLeave`, and `OnPaint` to draw a button to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

hope my reply helps you

Select the button

Go to its properties and change the button style to FLAT

In the same property widow now select FLAT SETTINGS

And you can see color to appear when clicked or hover on it...